# Not showing tables with Null value when i select *

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

when i tried to select * from a table i've created where i've inserted a null value in. the entire row of data which contains the null value will be omitted;

```
CREATE TABLE Credit_transactions (
CT_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Date_time DATE,
Money INT ,
Credits INT  ,
CT_type INT ,
Customer_id INT );
```

for example if a transaction does not include any money i will insert a null value when inserting the data such as;

```
INSERT INTO Credit_transactions(CT_id, Date_time, Money, Credits, CT_type, Customer_id)
VALUES('2', '10-DEC-2018', 'NULL', '3', '1', '1');
```

however after inserting all the data and upon trying to `select * from the table` i only get rows where theres no NULL values example i keyed id 1,2 and 3 id2 contains a null value in one of the columns, i will only get id1 and id3 after selecting all.

how can i fix this, i want to display the value as null value as it is E.g;

```
id:1 money:10
id:2 money:NULL
id:3 money 20
```

first time using stack overflow, and sorry for such a beginner question.

Comment: The values containing 'NULL' probably failed to insert and do not exist in the table. Instead of inserting NULL you insert a string 'NULL' in a field accepting integers only. So it is very likely to fail.

Comment: In addition to what has already been pointed out with your incorrect use of the character string 'NULL' (in single quotes) vs. the NULL indicator (the word NULL without quotes), your use of a character string to insert into a DATE column could prove to be problematic, depending on system/session settings of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  It's never a good idea to just present character string representation of a date, and expect Oracle to magically know how to interpret that format in converting it to and internal DATE.  Always use the to_date() function, so that you are always in complete control.

Comment: The incorrect use of 'NULL' would have produced an error which should have been a very strong clue.  At the very least you should have included that in your problem description.

Comment: Also you are inserting `'10-DEC-2018'` into a `date` column. In Oracle the syntax is [like this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).

Comment: In MySQL the syntax for date literals is [like this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html), which is different to Oracle but doesn't match `'10-DEC-2018'` either.

Comment: Depeding on the session setting, the date like this may go thru, but no session setting will let you insert 'NULL' in a column declared INT, supposing this is Oracle DB.

Comment: Not showing "tables", or not showing **rows**? I am tempted to edit your post to correct the title, but I am not sure if perhaps you did mean something different from "not showing rows". Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The column *Money* is declared as `INT`, and you are trying to insert a String value `'NULL'` instead of `NULL`, so the sql query will fail (inserting).
So it's obvious when selecting everything from the table, You wouldn't get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You have only inserted one row into the table.  That is why you are getting only one row in the result set.

If you want rows not in the table, you need something like a `left join`.  And you either need a table with the values you want or to create one in the table:

```
select x.ct_id, ct.money
from (select 1 as ct_id from dual union all
      select 2 as ct_id from dual union all
      select 3 as ct_id from dual
     ) x left join
     Credit_transactions ct
     on ct.ct_id = x.ct_id
```